# nullclines with variables

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I know how to solve nullclines, the following link is very helpful

http://mcb.berkeley.edu/courses/mcb137/exercises/Nullclines.pdf

However I don't understand how to solve equations that have only variables assuming from the Lotka–Volterra equations.

Take as example the following equations

dx/dt=ax+axy

dy/dt=ax^2+ay

how would I find the nullclines, and the fixed points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still proceed in the usual way, but your results will contain unspecified *constants* $ \ a \ , \ b \ , \ c \ , \ e \ , \ \text{and} \ f \  $ (only $ \ x \ $ and  $ \ y \ $ are the variables):

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} \ = \ 0 \ = \ x \ (a - by - ex) \ \ , \ \ \frac{dy}{dt} \ = \ 0 \ = \ y \ (cx - f)  \ . $$

So the nullclines are the $ \ x-$ and $ \ y-$ axes (the lines $ \ y = 0 \ $ and $ \ x = 0 \ $ ), the vertical line $ \ x = \frac{f}{c} \ , $ and the line $ \ ex + by = a \ . $  The fixed or equilibrium points are the intersection points of these various lines, where *both* derivatives are zero.  **EDIT:** There are three points for which that is the case (correcting an oversight I made -- thank you, **Amzoti**, for alerting me to this gaffe). So some of the coordinates of the points are going to be expressions involving those unspecified constants, rather than particular numbers.

**EDIT (3/27) --** Here are a couple of possible arrangements of the nullclines and fixed points (it is assumed here that the quantities represented require that  $ \ x \ge 0 \ $ and $ \ y \ge 0 \ $ .

For $ \ a, b, c, e, f \ > \ 0 \ , $ with $ \ \frac{a}{e}  >  \frac{f}{c}  >  1 \ , $ we have  (You are not yet asked to work out the "flow" in each region, but that will come up soon...)

[image]

By contrast, another possibility is to have  $ \ a, c, e, f \ > \ 0 \  \ \text{and} \ \ b < 0 \ $ with $ \ \frac{f}{c}  >  \frac{a}{e}  >  1 \ ; $ here, we have four fixed points, since the sloping nullcline does not intersect $ \ x = 0 \ $ for $ \ y \ge 0 \ . $

[image]

Comment: That's the tricky part: since there are no values assigned to the constants, there are various possible "flow fields" for this system, depending on the _relative_ values of the  constants.  I will add a couple example graphs in my post shortly to illustrate this.

Comment: If it's not met (as in the second graph), there will be a different configuration.  I've shown one each with the inequality between $ \ \frac{a}{e} \ $ and $ \ \frac{f}{c} \ $ running either way. Other situations can be produced by changing the sign of various of the constants.

Comment: _Definitely_ my mistake: I neglected to check for simultaneous solution!  I will edit my post and diagrams accordingly.  (I even _said_ both derivatives had to be zero, then didn't act on that...)

Comment: I should stop trying to write detailed responses in the "wee hours".  I got distracted by the regions of different flow directions and forgot to check my solutions for the _pair_ of equations.

Comment: I think I've got this sorted out now.  Thank you for spotting my oversights.