# Computing eigenvectors for an eigenvalue of a dynamical system

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

$\dot{x}=x\left ( 3-x-2y \right )$
$\dot{y}=y\left ( 2-x-y \right )$

In matrix form: $\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\ 
\dot{y}
\end{bmatrix}$
$=\begin{bmatrix}
\left ( 3-x-2y \right ) &0 \\ 
0& \left ( 2-x-y \right )
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix}$

To solve for the eigenvalues, we compute the Jacobian of the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
\left ( 3-x-2y \right ) &0 \\ 
0& \left ( 2-x-y \right )
\end{bmatrix}$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1}=3,\lambda_{2}=2$

The eigenvectors associated with $\lambda_{1}$:

$A-\lambda_{1}I=\begin{bmatrix}
\left ( 3-x-2y \right )-3 &0 \\ 
 0&\left ( 2-x-y \right )-3 
\end{bmatrix}$

Then,
$\left [ A-\lambda_{1} I|0 \right ]$, we get $\vec{V}=\left \langle 0,0 \right \rangle$

which is incorrect. Could anyone tell me where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Try solving $Av=\lamba_1v$, where $A$ has been evaluated at $x=0=y$.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing isn't making any sense, since it's a *nonlinear* system. It doesn't help that have written it "in matrix form", since the matrix depends on $x$ and $y$.

What you have to do first is to find the equilibrium points, then linearize around each of them. *Then* you can look at the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix at each equilibrium to find out whether it's stable or not.

Comment: What do you mean by linearise about each of the equilibrium points? I haven't solved for any eigensolution of any non-linear matrix before. Could I request for an example?

Comment: Here, for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729655/how-do-i-linearize

Comment: But if this problem is part of some course, you should have seen some explanation of the procedure in your textbook and/or in class.

Comment: How silly!( of me of course). My notes refer to this as 'computing the small disturbance from fixed point'.

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: The eigenvector is still unclear though. By linearising the non-linear system, I get an approximation of each equilibrium points but what is the mathematical method to computing the eigenvector for a non-linear system?

Comment: For each fixed point you get a **linear** system which approximates the behaviour of the nonlinear system near that point. And for these linear systems, you just compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to express $\dot x, \dot y$ as linear functions of $x$ and $y$, for example 
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}\dot x\\\dot y\end{array}\right] = A\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\1\end{array}\right]$$ for a matrix $A$. You can for example make a first order Taylor expansion of the original expressions (it is probably the easiest way to do). So assume you are close to the point $\left[\begin{array}{c} x_0\\ y_0\end{array}\right]$ and make a linear Taylor approximation there.

**Note** : The $A$ matrix should be a function of this point $\left[\begin{array}{c} x_0\\ y_0\end{array}\right]$.